# "Select your next badge" layout issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The "Select your next badge" dialog has a layout issue.  It looks like the boxes are too short, causing the text to overflow their rects.

The filled-in portion is also slightly misaligned with its badge (or progress bar).

[image]

It occurs for tag badges as well.

[image]

This is on Safari 9.0.3 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

Comment: Repro-ed on Chrome 48.0.2564.109 m

Comment: Same here in FF44.0

Comment: Same in Chrome 48.0.2564.109 on Ubuntu. Also this is network wide.

Comment: Asked also on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275844/310998

Comment: This issue was resolved earlier today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a network bug.

Caused by this line in `all.css`:

```css
.popup-badges .all-badge-progress .badge-progress` {
  height:76px;
  /*...other css*/
}
```

, a quick solution/fix would be to set the `height` to `98px` because (at least on SO) the `p` child has the maximum of 3 lines, so `98px` would be enough to have those 3 lines plus some bottom space and the tag-badges would have enough space as well.