# Broken layout in "Select your next badge" popup ("Available" tab only)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, popup

I have seen [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317187/select-your-next-badge-layout-issue), but here the issue is different...

The layout is broken in **Select your next badge** popup (*Next tag badge* and *Next badge*). It seems that the text input (*Search for a badge...*) is pushing down the layout when the **Available** tab is selected. This does not happen with *All*, *Gold*, *Silver* or *Bronze*.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Next tag badge]

[image: Next tag]

I am on **Arch Linux** and I have exactly the same problem in **Firefox** and **Chromium**.

---

**EDIT**

I do not know if it is related to my post, but something has changed a couple of minutes ago. Now I see this on my *Activity* page:

[image: Badges]

Comment: Reproducible on Windows with Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Calm down everyone - here's a freehand red circle highlighting the issue: http://imgur.com/XO9NwvZ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the badge popup issue. This has been corrected and will be fixed with the next production build.